# How to get dynamic selectors of multiple Highcharts on the same page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My application has a lot of Highchart charts, and all their selectors start with #highcharts-10 where the number inside is always different for the same chart. When there is just one chart on a page, I use `[id^='highcharts-']` inside of every selector. For example:

```
#highcharts-10 > svg > tspan
```

becomes:

```
[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan
```

I works perfectly, buy I can't figure out what can be done if I have three charts on the same page. Those chart IDs do appear to be in order with a +2 step. So if the first one is 10, the other two will be 12 and 14. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do with those nodes? Selector `[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan` should work well for all similar nodes

Comment: If there are three identical charts, they all have the same selectors where only one number inside is different. For example, `#highcharts-10 > svg > tspan`, `#highcharts-12 > svg > tspan`, and `#highcharts-14 > svg > tspan` will all be on the same page and will each belong to a different chart. So if I use `[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan`, how will webdriver know which element out of three to grab?

Comment: The first one found in DOM starting from root node

Comment: And then what selector do I use for the second and third ones?

Comment: Do you just want separate selectors for each node?

Comment: Yes, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish nodes with similar selectors, you can try

- search by unique XPath:

  ```
  first = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[starts-with(@id, "highcharts-")]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="tspan"])[1]')
  second = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[starts-with(@id, "highcharts-")]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="tspan"])[2]')
  third = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[starts-with(@id, "highcharts-")]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="tspan"])[3]')
  ```
- search by index of list of elements (note that `find_elements...` used instead of `find_element...`)

  ```
  first = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan")[0]
  second = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan")[1]
  third = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > tspan")[2]
  ```

Comment: @sprogissd, so did you try it?